# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property, for observable collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mvvm, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I'm trying to change the coordinated in an object I have In a observable collection. I'm using the MVVM model, and in my MainViewModel I'm creating an observable collection. In an different viewModel I wish to acess this observable collection however I get the error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

My problem is, when I change the observable collection to static I get an new Error, because of the way I'm adding the observable collection to my application. So is there a way work around the static part and acess the observable collection?

The code where my Observable collection is created:

```
   public ObservableCollection<CastleViewModel> CastlesInPlay { get; set; }
CastlesInPlay = new ObservableCollection<CastleViewModel>
        {
           (Adding parameters for CastlesInPlay)
        };
```

The code In which I wish to acess my observable collection:

```
  MainViewModel.CastlesInPlay[0].... = ...;
       MainViewModel.CastlesInPlay[0].... = ..;
```

Both of the classes are ViewModels, but when I add the castleInPlay to the my Views I go behind my views code and add them:

```
    private void AddCastle(CastleViewModel castleVM)
    {
        canvasCountries.Children.Add(new CastleUserControl() { DataContext = castleVM });
    }

    private void RemoveCastle(CastleViewModel castleVM)
    {
        canvasCountries.Children.Remove(canvasCountries.Children.Single(x => ((x as CastleUserControl).DataContext as CastleViewModel) == castleVM));
    }
        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainViewModel vm = ((MainViewModel)DataContext);

        vm.CastlesInPlay.ToList().ForEach(x => AddCastle(x));
        vm.AddCastleAction = x => AddCastle(x);
        vm.RemoveCastleAction = x => RemoveCastle(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CastlesInPlay` isn't static. Therefore, you *must* supply an instance of the class to access it:

```
var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
mainViewModel.CastlesInPlay ...;
```

You're accessing it like its static like this (which is wrong):

```
MainViewModel.CastlesInPlay ...;
```